# Creating a heatmap from polygons with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap with leaflet using Polygons as data. The data is stored as GeoJson. I have been trying to find a plugin for creating the Heatmap, but they only seem to work with points and not polygons. I am writing in JavaScript.

So far I have tried using the plugins from http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps.

Does anyone have any suggestions or direction?

Comment: You're speaking about what size of polygon ?

Comment: I'm not that much into polygons, so not completely sure how you refer to a polygons size. But they all vary in amount of points. Ranging from 3 to X.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate through your polygone ? So you could create a point for each value ?

Comment: I'm trying to do that now. Later on the issue would be that the polygon would just be a set of points without the area in between.

Comment: Can you explain how your heatmap should look like ?

Comment: The heatmap is supposed to show a list of polygons all over the map. If areas are covered with multiple polygons they will change color so it's easy to see which areas are covered by multiple polygons. I hope the explanation is clear. 
I have been searching a lot of places and it seems like my idea is a bit more complex than just importing a plugin.

Comment: And what about adding your polygon to the map with an opacity so if there is another polygon on top the opacity will be stronger ?

Comment: Yeah i think I am going to use your suggestions of lower opacity so you can see where there are multiple polygons on top of each other.
For making clusters I am going to use the polygon's center of mass as a point.

Comment: For me the opacity is the best idea for polygon in your case

Comment: Yeah, hopefully opacity will do. Thanks for the help :)